# Why does this print the error message twice?

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to stackoverflow, and new to python (python-3). Currently learning on edx.org and ran into the following error.

I created a function that checks a user-input **str** against the answer **str** and returns **True** or **False**.

When testing the function, I created a **while** loop to stop at the 3rd unsuccessful attempt. However, whenever there is an unsuccessful attempt, the function prints the error message twice when it should only print it once.

I fixed the error by storing the returning **Bool** value of the function into a variable rather than calling the function directly in the **if** condition within the **while** loop. However, I would like to understand the logic behind the error message printing twice. Here is the original code that prints the error message twice :

```
def letter_guess(letter, guess):

    if len(guess) == 1 and guess.isalpha() and guess < letter:
        print(guess,"is lower than the answer. Try again.\n")
        return False

    elif len(guess) == 1 and guess.isalpha() and guess > letter:
        print(guess,"is higher than the answer. Try again.\n")
        return False

    elif len(guess) == 1 and guess.isalpha() and guess == letter:
        print("Correct answer!")
        return True

    else:
        print("Please only enter one alphabet for the letter. Try again.\n")
        return False

answer2 = "m"
guess2 = input("Please enter a single alphabet : ")    

i = 0

while i < 3:


    if letter_guess(answer2, guess2):
        break

    elif letter_guess(answer2, guess2) == False and i == 2:
        print("You have reached 3 guesses. Game over.")
        break

    else:
        i += 1
        guess2 = input("Please guess again : ")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call the function twice, in first if and in elif, with the same wrong guess. You fixed it right calling only once and storing the return value.

I try to explain it better: the function is always called by the first if, to evaluate its condition; if return value is false, is called again to evaluate the elif condition, with same arguments as before.

Comment: Do you mean when the condition is not met, since the code runs through `if` and `elif`, it will run twice before ending in `else`? If so, I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You want to call `input()` inside the `while` loop:

```
# ...
answer2 = "m"
i = 0
while i < 3:
    guess2 = input("Please enter a single alphabet : ")
    # ...
```

Otherwise the user doesn't have a chance to change their answer, `guess2` never changes and they get the same error message multiple times.

Comment: Hey Andrea, there is already a new input for `guess2` at the end of the `while` loop.

Comment: @J.Choi: my bad, sorry, I missed it